# How to fix error "Unsupported source URL"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in an application with **react.js** and in it I have a form with image input, when uploading the image it is stored in the cloudinary service but it turns out that this process I cannot complete since that action returns the following:

```
POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUDNAME/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
error: {message: "Unsupported source URL: C:\fakepath\237959 (1).jpg"}
```

I leave the function

```js
function SubmitImgTest(img){
  const upload_preset = "***";
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('file',img );
  formdata.append('upload_preset', upload_preset);
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formdata,
  };
  fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/image/upload',options )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then (datos => console.log(datos))
}
export default SubmitImgTest;
```

Comment: what do you pass for `img`?

Comment: in `img` I receive an image that is the one I want to store in the cloudinary service

Comment: but what's the content in JS? is it a string, and object, ... can you add it to the question?